# How to return the most repeated value using a foreign key from a referring table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to create a SQL query to retrieve all the values from one unique row entry in a table called `JOBS`.

But to do so I need to use a table called `EMPLOYEES` which has a foreign key to the `JOBS` table.
The condition is to return the job_title from the table JOBS that has its job_id more times repeated in the `EMPLOYEES` table.

I need to do it with one SQL statement.

Desired output:

```
Stock Clerk
```

This is the query I have

```
SELECT job_id  
FROM (SELECT job_id FROM employees GROUP BY job_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc)  
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

but is not good enough because it is `job_title` from `EMPLOYEES` what I need.

Do you have any idea how can I do it? I am using an Oracle 11g database

This is how my tables look like:

**EMPLOYEES**

[image: EMPLOYEES]

**JOBS**

[image: JOBS]

Comment: Are those real phone numbers and salaries of real people? If not, that is some fine test data you've generated there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT job_title from JOBS where JOB_ID = (
SELECT job_id FROM employees GROUP BY job_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc LIMIT 1)
```

Don't remember offhand if you can use LIMIT 1 in oracle, but if not then

```
SELECT job_title from JOBS where JOB_ID = (
SELECT job_id FROM employees GROUP BY job_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc where ROWNUM=1)
```

Also note that if the top 2+ job id's are equal, it will only print one of them (i.e. if SA_REP and ST_CLERK both appeared 4 times, only one of them would be shown)
It's not clear what your requirements are for this, but the above queries would only return one of them